# javascript: how to save string substitution in another string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string and array

```
var s1 = "hello %s, i am %d years old";
var s2 =[John,24];
```

**Expected result:**

```
s3 = hello John i am 24 years old
```

I want to save the output into another string.
I'm able to display output in console

```
console.log(s1, ...s2)
```

But not able to store in other string.
I tried many things like:

```
var s3 = s1.format(...s2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that kind of string substitution only works in `console` methods.

Comment: Perhaps see: [JavaScript equivalent to printf/String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: const str = s1.replace(/\%(s|d)/g, () => s2[i++]) - works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no string formatter available in JS, you'd have to write that manually like

```
 let i = 0;
 s3 = s1.replace(/%(s|d)/g, (_, type) => s2[i++]);
```

Comment: doesn't work. It says. unkown variables '_' and 'type'.

Comment: Got error :Unnecessary escape character: \%  no-useless-escape
So I had to update s3 = s1.replace(/(s|d)/g, () => s2[i++]). but now the output is `hello %John, i am %24 yearundefined olundefined`

Comment: nm, correct syntax is `var s3 = s1.replace(/(%s|%d)/g, () => s2[i++]);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the template string from ES6:

```
let anotherString = `Hello ${s2[0]}, I am ${s2[1]} years old`;
```

You could use this too:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    a = this;
    for (k in arguments) {
      a = a.replace("{" + k + "}", arguments[k])
    }
    return a
}
```

Usage:

```
let anotherString = '{0} {1}!'.format('Hello', 'Word');
```

Than those solutions I dont see any other way to do that.

Comment: I want to save in another string, not to display in the console log.

Comment: @TheDeveloper My bad there you go!

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. The array and text can have any number of values so can't hardcode the index value of array.